# Why can't I create an array in ViewController?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, viewcontroller

When I try to create an array of UIButtons in the ViewController

**Instance member 'tile11' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'**

It works when I create it inside a method, but I need the array in more than one method, and it's getting annoying to having to create the array again and again.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tileArray: Array<UIButton> = [tile11, tile12, tile13, tile21, tile22, tile23, tile31, tile32, tile33]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't enough code to tell for sure, but I'm guessing `tile11` and the other tiles are other instance variables (button outlets to be specific)? They would technically not be accessible until run-time. This is why you cannot instantiate `tileArray` like that, but why it works in a method. The only way to instantiate `tileArray` in line with the declaration is to use constants in the array. You should initialize `tileArray` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. They are outlets yes.

Comment: When moving it to the `viewDidLoad()` I can't access it in my methods.

Comment: Declare it as `var tileArray: Array<UIButton>` outside methods so that all can see it, but assign the value in `viewDidLoad`.